# Обработка ошибок в express из блока try/catch

Tags: node.js, express

Выполняю асинхронные запросы к бд через async/await. Оборачиваю их в try/catch.

```
try {
    await something.find()
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send({error, desc: 'Ошибка при поиске чего-то там'})
}
```

Ошибка без проблем выводится в консоль, но в .send() попадает пустой объект.

Comment: Потому что `JSON.stringify(new Error) === '{}'`. Выбирайте явно `error.message`, например.

Comment: Да, я делал так, но почему-то думалось, что это костыль